# How can I replace a version number captured by regex with another one using SED?

Tags: shell, sed, regular-expression

I am trying with the following sed command:

```
sed 's/shared:core:([0-9]{1,4}(\.[0-9a-z]{1,6}){1,5})/shared:core:1.1.1/' test.txt
```

to replace the content of `test.txt`

```
shared:core:0.0.2
```

I expect it to become

```
shared:core:1.1.1
```

But nothing is happening. I think I need a little hint on how that works with sed

Comment: Please [edit] your question and explain what you are trying to capture with that regular expression. It _looks_ like you want to find 1 to 5 repetitions of "1-4 numbers followed by one to six repetitions of a `.` followed by one to 6 alphanumeric characters". But this doesn't make much sense with the input example you have given.

Comment: @terdon he is using parens for grouping, not capture.   He wants to normalize a version number, presumably for later operation on the file (like `diff`ing it with a reference version).

Comment: @DavidG. yes, I know. That's what I describe.

Comment: @terdon I simply want to replace 0.0.2 with 1.1.1 as described in the question

Comment: So all you need is `sed 's/0\.0\.2/1.1.1/`? If so, why do you have such a complicated regex? Are there any more lines in the file that you need to avoid?

Comment: You don't ask a newcomer why he is doing something wrong due the lack of experience - that is paradox. No I just need this one line to be changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `(foo)` which is mean to *capture* the string `foo`. However, by default, `sed` will read that as a literal `(` followed by `foo` and another `)` and since you don't have any `(` or `)` in your input, that will never match.

For `sed` to use capturing parentheses, you need t escape them `(\(foo\)`) or you need to use `-E`. You don't actually need this at all here though because you are never referring to the thing you were trying to capture. All you need is:

```
$ sed 's/shared:core:.*/shared:core:1.1.1/' file 
shared:core:1.1.1
```

Or even:

```
$ sed -E 's/(shared:core:).*/\1:1.1.1/' file 
shared:core::1.1.1
```

Or even simpler:

```
$ sed -E 's/(.*):.*/\1:1.1.1/' file 
shared:core:1.1.1
```

Now, if your input is more complicated and what you are trying to match is 1 to 5 repetitions of 1-4 numbers followed by one to six repetitions of a . followed by one to 6 alphanumeric characters (which is what the regex you used does), you can use your version, just add `-E` (assuming your `sed` implementation supports it):

```
$ sed -E 's/shared:core:([0-9]{1,4}(\.[0-9a-z]{1,6}){1,5})/shared:core:1.1.1/' file 
shared:core:1.1.1
```

Or, if you can't use `-E`:

```
$ sed  's/shared:core:\([0-9]\{1,4\}\(\.[0-9a-z]\{1,6\}\)\{1,5\}\)/shared:core:1.1.1/' file 
shared:core:1.1.1
```

Although I fear this might not be 100% portable, not sure.

Finally, remember that `sed` doesn't change the input file unless you give it the `-i` option. So if you are expecting the original file to change, use `sed -i .... file`.

Answer (score 1):

By default, `sed` uses basic regular expressions.  Add the `-E` option for extended regular expressions.  Thus:

```
sed -E 's/shared:core:([0-9]{1,4}(\.[0-9a-z]{1,6}){1,5})/shared:core:1.1.1/' test.txt
```

Alternatively, convert to a basic regular expression.  Thus:

```
sed 's/shared:core:\([0-9]\{1,4\}\(\.[0-9a-z]\{1,6\}\)\{1,5\}\)/shared:core:1.1.1/' test.txt
```

Additionally, if you actually want the contents of the file to change, then you need to add the `-i` option, to cause an "in place" change.  Thus:

```
sed -E 's/shared:core:([0-9]{1,4}(\.[0-9a-z]{1,6}){1,5})/shared:core:1.1.1/' -i test.txt
```

Comment: using `-E` did not change the `test.txt` version either

Comment: @xetra11 Are you expecting the file to change?

Comment: yes I do. I thought that is what sed does?

Comment: When using `sed -i -E ...` it always creates a new file called `test.txt-E`

Comment: @xetra11  For the GNU version of sed  (and probably most others),  `sed -i-E ...` will save the old file like test.txt-E, and will not use the extended regular expressions.  What you want is `sed -i -E ...`  Notice the space between `-i` and `-E`.

Comment: @xetra11 No, sed doesn't normally change its input.  sed normally reads from something that could be a file but is quite often a pipe, modifies it, and writes it to standard output, which is often also a pipe.  "sed" actually is from "Stream EDitor".  The `-i` option is a more recent addition that allows a file to be changed "inplace".   (`-E` is also more recent.)